# Back and forth SMS text messages replies in Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I am working on a twilio sms API.

I have many users on my website and all of these users have a particular form on their profile page.
when a visitor goes to particular user profile and fill out the form.

then i send an automatic message from Twilio to the visitor, which basically says "Thanks for filling my form i will be in touch with you shortly"

Now here comes the challenging part where i am lost.

When the visitor tries to reply to that message. i want that message reply to be received to the particular user whose profile form was filled up. so every particular user should be able to receive their own text messages and start back and forth conversation on SMS.

It will be a dynamic reply from both users and visitor's end.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need either a dedicated number per user, or tell your visitors to use some unique UserID when replying such as "User123: When will you contact me?".  Are you open to either of those options?

Comment: I don't think you'll need a unique number per user, but you likely will need to persist the To/From phone number pair of the initial thank you text.  That way when the user responds you can use that pair as a "Key" to know which form they filled out.  That only works though if they will only fill out one form.  If they might fill out multiple forms then you may need a unique phone number per form.

Comment: @DevinRader  Yeah, I was assuming that a visitor could fill out multiple forms.  If not, then it's pretty trivial.

Comment: @DevinRader On visitors reply, i don't want to send them auto reply. i want the visitor replies go to your user phone number and user should be able to reply to visitor back. is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into Twilio Conversations. You can find more information on conversations at the links below. Basically, you create a conversation and add participants to that conversation. Participants can be either SMS, MMS, WhatsApp, or Twilio Chat. Participants are assigned a Twilio Proxy Number with which they communicate through Twilio on.

[Introducing Twilio Conversations: Now, every message becomes an invitation for a conversation](https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-twilio-conversations)

[Using Twilio Conversations (Using Conversation You Tube Video - Signal 2019)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pkQ6dSvTlo)

[How to Use Twilio Conversations API (Twilio Chat to SMS tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKlv_8YFg2g)

[Twilio Conversations Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart)

[The Conversations API Overview](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api)

Answer (score 0):

Since users interact with you first through SMS and you want to continue the conversation with them through SMS.

This is the steps I would take

1. [Receive and Reply to SMS Message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-php). The example is in PHP but you can find an example in other languages.
2. You can reply with users SMS with [Create a SMS Conversation using HTTP cookies with Webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-create-sms-conversations-php)

Comment: Thank you, the links that you have sent seems pretty much straight forward to implement, however i don't understand how a particular user would receive the message from the visitor. how it would recognize, if that message from a particular user?

Comment: on visitor reply, i don't want to send them auto reply.
i want the visitor replies go to your user phone number and user should be able to reply to visitor back.